# how to create a method that returns conditional type

Tags: c#

I have a Method as follows in one of my projects that retuns byte[] if my pictureboxstupic contains an image.
while I want to convert it in such a way that if there is no picture in pictureboxstupic it should return string = "NULL" else it should return bute[].
how can I do that??

```
private byte[] GetPic()
{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        var bmp = new Bitmap(pictureboxstupic.Image);
        bmp.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        stream.Position = 0;
        var data = new byte[stream.Length];
        stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
        return data;
    }
}
```

Note: 
The column in which I am inserting image is as follows

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Students] 
([Photo] [image] NULL)
```

and in my current condition I'm inserting the image in my above mentioned columns i.e Students.Photo like this

```
if (pictureboxstupic.Image == null)
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Photo", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "NULL";
}
else
{
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Photo", SqlDbType.Image).Value = GetPic();
}
```

Comment: Why, oh why, would you ever want to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@empi's answer is the right one, and I'd like to expand on it: 
Methods and functions should have a tightly defined set of responsibilities. In the case of your `GetPic` method, it's to get an image's byte stream. That should be the extent of the logic encapsulated in that method.

Displaying the word "NULL" in some error-box is *not* `GetPic`'s responsibility. It's the responsibility of whomever calls it and is in charge of displaying the image or the error message. That's why I think `GetPic` should just return `null` if it's a reasonable condition to receive no image, or perhaps even throw an exception if it's a real error condition that breaks the program flow.

What you *shouldn't* do in any case is return an `object` that can be either `byte[]` or `string`, since that defeats the whole point of a strongly typed environment, and is a great way to introduce bugs later on. If you must return either a `byte[]` or a `string`, you can either use the `ref/out` params as suggested by others, or create a new class called `ImageData`, or whatever, that contains both the bytes and the error message, which you can use to retrieve either one or the other.

-- EDIT

After your clarification, I'll still stick by my answer. You *shouldn't* be doing that. Databases support a NULL value that is *not* the same as the string "NULL". Rather than inserting this string, you should make sure your column is nullable, and insert the null value - `DBNull.Value`. Your current code will crash, because the Photo column cannot handle VarChar values.

Comment: Yes, the answer you've added is the proper way to solve this: the method returns null, and the DB code saves DBNull.Value.

Comment: Avner brother I've done as you asked me to accept the answer that helped me the most. I found your answer the most helping as you not only suggested me how to solve me problem but also told me what was wrong even the problem was solved. that is I was inserting the string "NULL" instead of null or DbNull.Value. But I didn't understand what is this Stream.ToArray?? How will I use this in my coding

Answer (score 4):

You may always return object and cast it to type you expect - but it is not a good idea. It would be better if you just check if pictureboxstupic is empty before calling your method and then execute proper logic (e.g. assigning "NULL").

You may also apply similar semantic to [TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx) - that is you may return bool that would answer if pictureboxstupic wasn't empty and return byte array as an out parameter.

Comment: I've Edited my question. May be it will help you to help me

Answer (score 1):

return `object` instead? Then cast based by first checking the type using the `is` keyword.

```
if(returnedType is string) //or use as and then check for NULL
{

}
else   //type is byte[]
{
}
```

Not sure about your use case and whether it is valid or not, but this can be a solution

Comment: I've Edited my question. May be it will help you to help me

Answer (score 1):

You can make it by three solutions:

1.) Use object as return type

2.) Use 'ref' and 'out' parameter specifiers to return array and make method return type string for returning status message.

3.) Use 'unsafe' code for pointers...

Example:

```
    public string GetPic(out byte[] ret)
    {
        if (Image == null)
            return "NULL";
        //set ret's value as image bytes
        return "ok";
    }
```

Comment: can you plz use my coding to answer me. how would i use object as a return type?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like:

```
        //call the method:
        string str = ""; //variable that will be changed accordingly by returned value
        byte[] image = GetPic();
        if (image.Length == 0)
        {
            //do what ever you want, like string = "NULL":
            str = "NULL";
        }
    //
    //

    private byte[] GetPic()
    {
        PictureBox pictureboxstupic = new PictureBox();
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var bmp = new Bitmap(pictureboxstupic.Image);
            bmp.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            stream.Position = 0;
            var data = new byte[stream.Length];
            stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
            return data;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I solved my problem like this
Method:

```
private object GetPic()
{
    if(pictureboxstupic.Image == null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        var bmp = new Bitmap(pictureboxstupic.Image);
        bmp.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        stream.Position = 0;
        var data = new byte[stream.Length];
        stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
        return data;

    }
}
```

usage:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Photo", SqlDbType.Image).Value = GetPic() ?? DBNull.Value;
```

Comment: You can simplify the code by simply calling `stream.ToArray()`, which wraps up the whole read-into-an-array code. Also, it's good that you've managed to solve the problem, but I'd appreciate it if you accept the answer that helped you get to it.

Comment: Avner I request you to plz edit the coding of my answer as you want me to do. I'm not getting where to use stream.ToArray() and ok I'm gonna accept the answer that helped me to solve my problem